# Syntax error with creator method in Twilio in Java

Tags: java, api, message, twilio-api, phone-number

I'm using Twilio in Java to send or receive text messages. I added *twilio-7.47.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar* to the project Java library and executed the following syntax based on an example in Twilio's website.

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

public class Example {

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC41b4ea83f681353d261d5d0997d73b30";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "my_auth";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Message message = Message.creator(
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+15558675310"),
                new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
                "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?")
            .create();

        System.out.println(message.getSid());
    }
}
```

I have a syntax error with the creator method and it is: **The method creator(String) in the type Message is not applicable for the arguments (PhoneNumber, PhoneNumber, String)**

I looked at many websites related to this subject and all of them use the same syntax for this task.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: are you importing `import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;`

Comment: Yes. I already imported them.

Comment: Try cleaning your project (i.e., deleting all build artifacts) and rebuilding. I was unable to reproduce your error with the given code. I suspect you may have some old stuff in your classpath.

Comment: It worked! Thank you